# Differential Equations first order

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Anyone who can help me on this equation, **$y' = (\frac{y}{x + y^3})$**  I've already tried to make a substitution which is: $h(x,y) = x+y^{3}$ and did the derivatives but still no solution, so if anyone knows something, a simple lead. Thanks

Comment: Any own thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice, we have $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x+y^3}$$ $$ydx-(x+y^3)dy=0$$ Compare with $Mdx+Ndy=0$, we get $$M=y\iff \frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=1$$ $$N=-(x+y^3)\iff \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=-1$$ We find that $$\frac{\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}}{M}=\frac{-1-1}{y}=\frac{-2}{y}=f(y)$$ Hence, the integration factor is $$I.F.=e^{\int f(y)dy}=e^{\int \frac{-2}{y}dy}=e^{-2\ln y}=\frac{1}{y^2}$$ Now, multiplying I.F. on both the sides, we get

$$\frac{1}{y^2}ydx-\frac{1}{y^2}(x+y^3)dy=0$$

$$\frac{1}{y}dx-\left(\frac{x}{y^2}+y\right)dy=0$$
$$\color{}{\frac{1}{y}}dx+\left(-\frac{x}{y^2}\color{}{-y}\right)dy=0$$

Above is the exact differential equation of form $Mdx+Ndy=0$ 
By comparison, we get $$M=\color{red}{\frac{1}{y}}, \ N=-\frac{x}{y^2}\color{blue}{-y}$$

Now, its solution is given as 
$$\int_{y=\text{constant}} Mdx+\int(\text{terms of N not containing x}) dy=c$$
$$\int \color{red}{\frac{1}{y}}dx+\int (\color{blue}{-y}) dy=c$$
$$\frac{1}{y}\int dx-\int y dy=c$$
$$\frac{x}{y}-\frac{y^2}{2}=c$$
Hence, the solution of ODE

$$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{\frac{x}{y}-\frac{y^2}{2}=c}}$$